# my flutter project creates folders build 1, build 2, build 3 etc

Tags: flutter

[image: screenshot of flutter folder layout]

It does not affect anything but size of project - hence git push takes forever.

I already tried deleting it once but it appears again once flutter run and continues where it stopped making new folders with every fresh run or so.

I am using MacOS

Let me know if you need more information!

Appreciate any help!

Comment: maybe its because I have the whole project saved on my Desktop which is connected with iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

So apparently my mac optimized the storage and deleted some (unused) parts of the project which triggered flutter to make the new folders. In the end I needed to compress the whole project to be able to move it on the internal disk (somewhere on user) and then deleted all extra folders with the initial folders. I then ran the command `flutter create .` to create all folders. After a `flutter clean` it was running without any problems or creating extra folders.

Lesson learned: never create a flutter project within iCloud Drive folders.